# Multi-dimensional indexing of numpy arrays along inner axis

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

- I have a numpy array `x` with shape `[4, 5, 3]`
- I have a 2D array of indices `i` with shape `[4, 3]`, referring to indices along dimension 1 (of length 5) in `x`
- I'd like to extract a sub-array `y` from `x`, with shape `[4, 3]`, such that `y[j, k] == x[j, i[j, k], k]`
- How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct answer is as follows:

```py
y = x[np.arange(4).reshape(4, 1), i, np.arange(3).reshape(1, 3)]
```

Example:

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

x = np.arange(4 * 5 * 3)
rng.shuffle(x)
x = x.reshape(4, 5, 3)
i = rng.integers(5, size=[4, 3])

y = x[np.arange(4).reshape(4, 1), i, np.arange(3).reshape(1, 3)]

print("x:", x, "i:", i, "y:", y, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
x:
[[[16 27 20]
  [ 8 42 34]
  [51  4 52]
  [57 10  2]
  [44 23 24]]

 [[43 11 35]
  [30 18 54]
  [ 3  1 55]
  [17 21 36]
  [ 0 28  6]]

 [[19 48 22]
  [26 37 46]
  [58 32 25]
  [53  9 38]
  [47 50 40]]

 [[13 12  7]
  [45 39 59]
  [ 5 49 14]
  [29 41 56]
  [33 15 31]]]
i:
[[1 3 4]
 [0 0 3]
 [1 2 0]
 [4 2 4]]
y:
[[ 8 10 24]
 [43 11 36]
 [26 32 22]
 [33 49 31]]
```

(Rubber-duck debugging FTW)

Comment: yes, the key concept is `broadcasting`. You want a (4,3) result.  (4,1), (4,3), (3,) broadcast together to produce this.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy-take-along-axis):

```
y = np.take_along_axis(x, i[:, None, :], axis=1)[:, 0, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

A generalized method using `np.ix_` that can be applied to any arbitrary `axis`:

```
axis = 1
t = np.ix_(*(range(s) for s in [*x.shape[:axis], *x.shape[axis+1:]]))
y = x[*t[:axis], i, *t[axis:]]
```

---

A slightly less memory-consuming but ad-hoc alternative:

```
y = x[[[v] for v in range(x.shape[0])], i, range(x.shape[2])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do:

```
y = x[np.arange(4)[:, None], i, np.arange(3)]
```